# center align overlapping image in middle of another image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show play button in center of the main image and want it to automatically align it self in center on different screen sizes.

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/w75vaho2/1/)

I tried different thing and sort of gave it up, i am not sure if i am using wrong structure or same thing can be done in easy and better way.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="video-item-wrapper">
        <div class="video-image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="play-item-wrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50.png/09f/fff" />
        </div>
        <div class="video-details-wrapper"> <span>this is video title</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add css

```
.video-item-wrapper{  position: relative;}
.play-item-wrapper{position: absolute;top: 50%;  left: 50%;margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;z-index: 9999;}
```

Comment: It breaks when if have different size text example https://jsfiddle.net/w75vaho2/19/

Comment: what would you like to do.Should it print in the same line??

Comment: after every 2 divs use 

<div class="clearfix"></div> and as style 

.clearfix{clear: both}

Refer : https://jsfiddle.net/w75vaho2/24/

Answer (score 0):

One another solution is use following:

```
.video-item-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}


 .play-item-wrapper {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/w75vaho2/17/)

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you have make changes in HTML for that. Check https://jsfiddle.net/w75vaho2/23/